# How do I stop rfkill module from hardblocking my wifi, without rfkill command?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, linux-kernel, wifi-configuration

I went into my BIOS the other day, didn't change anything, and rebooted.  After this, my wifi was hardblocked.  I looked online for solutions, and learned of the rfkill command.  But I get

```
rfkill: command not found
```

However, in the startup messages, I see rfkill being called for something.  I thought that perhaps it wasn't in the path for some reason.  I'm sure it was. (I'll double check that tonight.)

I tried running Linux Mint off a flash drive, and the rfkill command told me that my wifi was hardblocked.  I could unblock everything but the wifi hardblock.

There is no wifi switch on my computer.  There is a wifi button the keyboard (F12) but it does nothing.

I'd like to know how to fix this obviously, but also I'd like to know why the hell this happened.

UPDATE! 2014.10.5
I've done some investigating and I want to share it, in case someone spots something that can solve this.

I rabbit-holed my way through the beginner's guide, and these are the results:

identify name of wireless interface

```
$ iw dev
wlp3s0
```

use wifi-menu to connect to a network

```
# wifi-menu wlp3s0
Scanning for networks... failed
No networks found
```

bring interface up

```
# ip link set wlp3s0 up                             
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill

# rfkill list
bash: rfkill: command not found
```

I see mention of rfkill in the startup messages, but not in dmesg.
rfkill works in Linux Mint flash drive.  When I run that, it will change block on all except hard block.  There is no hardware switch.

show loaded modules:

```
# lsmod
```

produces big list, which includes:

```
rfkill                 18867  4 cfg80211,toshiba_acpi,bluetooth
iwlwifi               156837  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              454161  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm

# modinfo rfkill
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.3-1-ARCH/kernel/net/rfkill/rfkill.ko.gz
license:        GPL
description:    RF switch support
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
author:         Ivo van Doorn <IvDoorn@gmail.com>
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.3-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           master_switch_mode:SW_RFKILL_ALL ON should: 0=do nothing (only unlock); 1=restore; 2=unblock all (uint)
parm:           default_state:Default initial state for all radio types, 0 = radio off (uint)
```

Does that mean everything is blocked by default?

What happens if I blacklist rfkill?
I created `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
Inside it says:

```
 #do not load this.
 blacklist rfkill
```

Rebooting to see if this did anything...
rfkill still loaded.  Rebooted again...
Got a stream of iwlwifi errors:

```
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:
Failed to load firmware chunk!
Could not load the [0] uCode section
Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

I don't think that this is related to the new conf file because I had this error a few days ago.  It doesn't happen every time.  As far as the conf file goes: I guess it still loaded because something depends on it.  If I still want to try to stop it, I can use the install command I read about.

But at this point, I think I should try to reinstall the firmware?
Does anyone have any input or ideas other than that?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on my Raspberry.  A simple

```
sudo apt-get install rfkill
```

did the job.  I was then able to unblock my devices with

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: This obviously does not answer the question, which is how to do it *without* the rfkill command.

Comment: @Flimzy, it isn't obvious. I got lost trying to follow what the objective is; couldn't tell if rfkill might not be installed on the system (just on a flash drive), or there might be a problem with the installation. It isn't even clear whether it's a package and needs to be installed, or is built into the kernel, but netlinker installed it as a package. My read was the OP just wants to get the job done, and rfkill could be a solution if it was working. If that's the case, this answer might not be totally off-target. The OP has been back since this answer was posted and didn't provide feedback.

Comment: While this temporary solution will work once after a boot, the problem will remain with each subsequent boot.

Answer (score 1):

check your `udev` rules... if there is a rule alike that, comment it out (or set `ATTR{state}="1"`):

```
# SUBSYSTEM=="rfkill", ATTR{type}=="bluetooth", ATTR{state}="0"
```

while one can define the default state for the rfkill **device** with `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf`:

```
options rfkill master_switch_mode=2
options rfkill default_state=1
```

while in most cases, an `ACPI` or `WMI` module is responsible for dispatching the hardware buttons, which is not working properly and therefore leaving the radio in "hard off" state, impossible to enable through software. One can blacklist these module:

```
blacklist hp_wmi
blacklist acer_wmi
...
```

Ordinary `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e acpi` should show which one it is... while the listed module `toshiba_acpi` might be worth an attempt to `blacklist toshiba_acpi` (this might require another kernel switch, in order to have the back-light brightness working properly).

The `rfkill` command would even be available on [Mint](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/rfkill), while the output of `rfkill list` would be interesting, in order to determinate if it's a "hard block" (caused by hardware buttons) or "soft block".

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist wmi
```

rfkill will show:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't work.  wmi is still loaded.  So I used 'install wmi /bin/false' and that stops it from loading.  However, the rfkill problem remains.  I will try to do the same thing through a Mint flash drive.

Comment: ok, well it is a definite fix but as you mentioned it seems you need to restart some of the services for it to work correctly.

Comment: It's clearly not a definite fix.  It didn't work at all.

Comment: ok, I thought it would as i had a similar issue and it worked for me

Comment: this didn't work for me either, rfkill still randomly disables my WiFi

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You can reach rfkill by using sysfs file system. I have tested this only on Debian though.

if you run `systemctl` without any parameters it lists everything it controls. In the `devices` list, you should find the **rfkill** device. And the name points to the **sysfs** path.

Name:

```
sys-devices-virtual-misc-rfkill.device ....    loaded active plugged ...
```

If you follow that path, you will see the device's parameters. But you cannot control the device from there. According to the [kernel documents](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-class-rfkill), the device control path is `/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill*/`. The asterisk denotes a number assigned to each device. In my situation, there is only 1 device which is `rfkill0`.

In the directory, you will see files named `hard` and `soft`.  If you `cat` the files you will see the contents as `0` or `1`. If `hard` is `1` this means a hardware switch or similar blocks the driver. This means there must be a hardware switch. If `soft` is `1` this means the software blocks the driver.

To unblock just put a `0` into the `soft` file like:

```
echo 0 > soft
```

Now if you `ifup wlan0` it should start working.

When you restart your PC the setting will go blocking again. So you can create a systemd service that resolves the soft block.

Answer (score -1):

mint 19 and levono z560, (no bluetooth)

pc was rfkill hard block, not from hardware switch, nor keyboard.

unplugging the laptop power cord when the pc is off, (yes off) enables  wifi, no rfkill block.  My battery is weak, I think they block wireless if they think the battery is low.

fixed for me!!!